# Is N the total number of nodes in the frontier plus the number of nodes in the explored list?

Tags: search, heuristics, a-star, norvig-russell, branching-factors

I'm studying fundamentals of AI from the classic Russell-Norvig book (3rd edition). I have a small doubt about the effective branching factor, which is defined as follows (section 3.6.1, p. 103):

> One way to characterize the quality of a heuristic is the effective branching factor $b^{*}$. If the total number of nodes generated by $\mathrm{A}^{*}$ for a particular problem is $N$ and the solution depth is $d$, then $b^{*}$ is the branching factor that a uniform tree of depth $d$ would have to have in order to contain $N+1$ nodes. Thus,
> $$
> N+1=1+b^{*}+(b^{*})^{2}+\cdots+(b^{*})^{d}
> $$

So, is $N$ the number of nodes in frontier + the number of states in the explored list, or should I also consider the generated nodes those that were generated but then discarded because already in the frontier or explored?

Also, I tried implementing a program that between the other things can calculate the effective branching factor for instances of a specific problem and I noticed two things:

1. When the problem is 'large' but the solution is 'close" (like two actions from starting state), the computed $b^{*}$ is HUGE (it even got as high as 500).
2. In the same conditions as before it happened that $b^{*} > b$ (I'd dare to say in some cases $b^{*} \gg b$).

Is all of this reasonable?